# Сохранение базы данных

Tags: c#, access

Прошу помочь разобраться с сохранением базы данных.
Добавляю данные и сохраняю:
this.clientTableAdapter.Update(this.databaseDataSet.Client);

После Update непосредственно в БД все изменяется (в папке bin, но не изменяется в корне), но после перезапуска снова все чисто.
В свойствах БД уже менял "Не копировать/Копировать если новое" - не помогает. 
Буду признателен за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы же сами написали - в папке bin все меняется после вызова Update. Значит данные сохраняются в БД.

Проверьте что в момент запуска файл действительно не копируется в bin - просто сравните размер до билда, после билда, и после запуска приложения. Если копируется - ищите в какой именно момент - при билде или при запуске.

Comment: В этом то и проблема. При старте копирует БД из корня в bin (при этом в свойствах базы стоит "не копировать"). Возможно я упустил еще какие-то свойства?

Comment: @АлександрСергеев Должно хватить "не копировать". Попробуйте сделать копию проекта и убрать из него все остальные файлы. Если в ней все еще будет копировать файл. - включите в Options / Project and Solutions/Build and Run/MSBuils output verbosity в Detailed и поищите упоминания файла в окне Output после билда.

Comment: PashaPash - спасибо огромное. Создал копию и переподключил БД - все заработало.